# SQL IN Operator With Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select from table1 in table2 where table2 contains a specific date range. I have tried quite a few different queries; some of which i receive syntax errors, and some where the date range is not working.

**Currently:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT f
FROM table1
WHERE f IN(f.table2) as s
WHERE s.time > '2013-01-01 00:00:00' AND s.time < '2013-01-07 00:00:00'
ORDER BY s.time
```

What is the correct syntax for this type of in statement? All examples I see are:

```
Select *
From table1
Where x in(table2);
```

I can't find any more in depth examples. Any suggestions are appreciated, please leave a comment for more information if needed.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  You might be surprised to learn that non-working code often doesn't express intentions very well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - i added a picture to try to show what i have an what i expect. i made different dates, but i mainly am trying to show that i want dates ordered and within a week's time.

Comment: How should a simle table1 and table2 look?

Answer (score 1):

A `WHERE` clause can exist only once in a query unless it's inside a `SUBQUERY`, to use the `IN` clause with another `SELECT` you need to follow this pattern:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE X IN ( SELECT OneColumnOnly FROM Table2)
  AND TIME BETWEEN '1/1/2012' AND '1/1/2013'
```

Column X from TABLE1 must be the same type as `OneColumnOnly` from TABLE2 or implicitly convert to it like an `INT` to a `VARCHAR`

Comment: A join would be faster and clearer, but the question is already quite nebulous...

Comment: Can I not use an alias on the `in` statement before the `and` statement? `unexpected token: as near line 1`

Comment: you'd have to post your SQL for me to answer.